# How to use array value as a class object name in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use an object name from the array. I know I wrote wrong code below inside the loop. How should I write code on the below pointer lines for using object name from the array?

[image]

Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Students{
    public:
        int index;
        string name;
        string father;
};
int main() {
    string nname[] = {"John", "Doe"};
    string fname[] = {"Ex John Father", "Ex Doe Father"};

    int NarrSize = sizeof(nname)/sizeof(nname[0]); // Size of nname array
    int FarrSize = sizeof(fname)/sizeof(fname[0]); // Size of fname array

    if( NarrSize == FarrSize ){ // Check if both array size is same
       for(int i=0; i<NarrSize; i++){
            Students nname[i];

            nname[i].index  = i+1;
            nname[i].name   = nname[i];
            nname[i].father = fname[i];
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Students nname[i];` is not legal in c++ among other things. Like an off by 1 error and it goes out of scope at the next iteration

Comment: A variable name in c++ must be known at compile time its not something that exists or can change at runtime

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is `std::map<std::string,Students>`

Answer (score 4):

You should allocate the array before the loop.

Also the name `nname` is already used as the array of `string`, so you should give another name to your array of `Students`.

Using non-standard VLA (variable-length array):

```
    if( NarrSize == FarrSize ){ // Check if both array size is same
       Students student_array[NarrSize]; // allocate array
       for(int i=0; i<NarrSize; i++){

            student_array[i].index  = i+1;
            student_array[i].name   = nname[i];
            student_array[i].father = fname[i];
        }
    }
```

Using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
    if( NarrSize == FarrSize ){ // Check if both array size is same
       std::vector<Students> student_array(NarrSize); // allocate vector
       for(int i=0; i<NarrSize; i++){

            student_array[i].index  = i+1;
            student_array[i].name   = nname[i];
            student_array[i].father = fname[i];
        }
    }
```

Add `#include <vector>` to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Well, in both cases, we now have a collision between the `Students` collection named `nname` and the `std::string` collection also named `nname`. But yes, it seems like the ultimate goal is to try to create a collection of `Students` and this will do that with a different variable name.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thank you for notifying. Collision fixed.

Comment: @MikeCAT Inside the for-loop, every increment should get a different object name as array value. If I remove the first line and don't specify the name inside of the for-loop so where the value will assign? because `nname` has 2 array values and each value should be an object for Students class.

Comment: @Naiem I don't understand your concern. My advice is to try the second of the 2 example codes here however to make it valuable you actually need to do something with the vector after the loop fills it. Perhaps a range based for loop that prints all items in the vector.